# lambda function to call redshift user defined function or query

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-lambda, udf

I was looking for a simple example of a lambda function to call a redshift user defined function or just a query and was surprised to not find anything that simple.

Does someone have an example they could share or some tips to head me in the correct direction?

Comment: What language do you need an example in? Why would this example be any different than regular (non Lambda) code that runs a Redshift query?